# why are my eclipse code error labels lagging

Tags: eclipse, ide, syntax-error

so when you make syntax errors, etc, eclipse will automatically put in an x button on the line number and then when you fix the error, that x button is supposed to disappear

normally, it should disappear right after the error is fixed, but in my case, it would disappear for up to 5 seconds after the error is fixed which is abnormal

anyone knows why this is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior your describe is not abnormal. Validation is expensive and if done completely in realtime would bog down your actions (like typing). Instead, validation tasks are queued and are typically executed during a pause in keyboard activity. If you type energetically, you will notice that the validation doesn't update for quite a while. The exact experience will also vary with the power of your computer.

Comment: no but even when I stop typing it still waits for many many seconds

Comment: That maybe just be a fixed delay after the end of activity. Are you observing different behavior on other computers?